# "zipAlignExe' does not exist." error while running my project on Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle

I'm getting error below this,

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':project1:zipalignDebug'.
> File 'D:\Program Files\Android Studio\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe' specified for property
'zipAlignExe' does not exist.
```

I downloaded all packages in sdk, I downloaded twice a packages about zipAlign but it didn't solve my problem.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Does it exist? Did you install the SDK on D:, or C:?

Comment: D: of course. But I checked the /tools file but I couldn't find zipAlign.exe

Comment: If you downloaded a zip in Windows and then unzipped it, sometimes it omits the .exe files (in case they are malware). Perhaps that is the problem? (You can fix by right-clicking the zip and unblocking it.)

Comment: I found zipAlign.exe in other directory. I copied it and pasted. And it works. Thank you for your attention

Comment: I had the same problem, but got it resolved by updating Android Studio / build tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you run into the following Gradle build error after updating your Android SDK:

> A problem was found with the configuration of task ':MyApp:zipalignRelease'.
>   File '/home/user/SDKs/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/zipalign' specified for property 'zipAlignExe' does not exist.

Therefore, I updated the [android-sdk-setup script](https://gist.github.com/johnjohndoe/6442719) to also symlink `zipalign`. Gradle now finds what it is looking for. Happy building!

Comment: Hey @JJD I could not solve my issue , can you please explain me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please open a new question with a detailed description of you problem and error messages.

Comment: How do I open this script file?

Comment: @Suraj You can use any editor such as *vim* or *emacs*. If you want to run the script then use the following command at your shell `$ ./path/to/android-sdk-setup.sh`. Please consider opening a new question if you want to ask further.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Gradle, updating the Gradle plugin from 0.10 to 0.11 worked for me:

```
buildscript {
    ...

    dependencies {
        ...
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a head's up to other intellij users - 0.11.+ currently causes the issue described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633529/classcastexception-apiversionimpl-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-integer

Comment: Got to love Gradle, if you use the Gradle plugin 0.10 you can't make a release. But if you use the Gradle plugin 0.11 you can't use Intellij or Android Studio.

Comment: Gradle and Android are still moving fast. Just use anything higher than 0.10 (i.e. I'm currently using '0.12.+')

Answer (score 2):

I got the answer here:
http://tech.sarathdr.com/questions/question/gradle-is-failing-with-new-android-sdk-versio-zipalign-is-missing

It says: 
New android sdk version (23) does not contain the file zipalign file. You can download the old version of android sdk and copy zipalign file to the tools folder

Comment: I dont think this is the right way. Use latest Gradle plugin to fix the issue. I used 0.12.0 to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error before, here's what I have done

Go to 
`C:\...\Users\your-name\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools`
you have to reach up to build tools.
than there you will get list of build tools.
[image]

Here you have to just copy `Zipalign.exe` from older to newer version .

It worked for me. I used it in `BluetoothLegatt` sample code.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, make sure your ANDROID_HOME is pointing to the right folder. For me it was:

```
C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321
```

I updated it but I forgot to point to the newer SDK folder:

```
C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk
```

Now I'm sure I'm using the last SDK tools for Android.

Ok, now update the gradle script:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
}
```

and

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"
```