# ClassCastException: ApiVersionImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

Tags: java, android, build, gradle

I have android + gradle project. The following exception appears when I try to start application:

`'ClassCastException: com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ApiVersionImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer: com.android.build.gradle.internal.model.ApiVersionImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer'`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.0.1'
    apt 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:3.0.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '19.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you updated all your dependencies via the sdk manager and synced gradle?

Comment: May be [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=70926#c33) helps.

Comment: Xinzz, all synced. 
Jens, thanks but it didn't help.

Comment: I just ran into a similar issue. Did you finally get over it?

Comment: I changed plugin version ...  

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.0'

Comment: Alright. Thanks. Unfortunately I need a feature that comes with 0.11.

Comment: Just in case sombebody else runs into this. I had to install the most recent version of android studio to make it running along with gradle 0.11 or 0.12 respectively.

Comment: Thanks @HermannKlecker. I can also confirm that downloading the latest version of Android Studio solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=ApiVersionImpl&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=72816) open to google. For Intellij 13.1.4 it is still failure.

Rolling back build tools version to 1.10.+ can help.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'
    }
}
```

I realized that [IDEA Intellij 14 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+14+EAP) has no such problem and support Android L as well.

Comment: this took from me so much time :(

Comment: Use newest version of Android Studio. IntelliJ hopefully will fix this next release.

Comment: Just a head's up, if you revert to 0.10 you'll run into this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586688/zipalignexe-does-not-exist-error-while-running-my-project-on-android-studio